# System.Net.WebException: 'Error en el servidor remoto: (502) Puerta de enlace no válida.'

Tags: c#, aws

Estoy tratndo de consumir esta api que cree con web serverless y tengo el siguiente error
System.Net.WebException: 'Error en el servidor remoto: (502) Puerta de enlace no válida.'
si hago la solicitud en poustman funciona bien . me podrian ayudar a solucionar este error?
mi codigo esta en una aplicacion web de c# (ASP.web forms)

```
   WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https:miapi");
        request.Method = "POST";
 
        string postData = ("{ \"paramether1\": \"content\", \"parameter2\": Content\"}");
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
 
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
  
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
  
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
   
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
  
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
 
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        char[] delimiters = new char[] { '{', '[', ',', '}', ']', '\'', ';' };
        string[] parts = responseFromServer.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string c in parts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
        Console.Read();
     
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Comment: En la primera línea `WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https:miapi");` el parámetro del método `Create` debe ser la dirección del recurso. Qué valor estás utilizando cuando lo haces desde el Postman?

Comment: la direccion de mi api y como tal le mando el objeto json que recibe dos parametros

Comment: Esa misma dirección es la que debes colocar en el método `Create` para reemplazar el valor que actualemte tiene: `"https:miapi"`

Comment: si lo hago como tal no puedo poner el api real pero es claro que va ahi